# jQuery filter() traversing doesnt seems to work?

Tags: jquery, filter, traversal

I dont know what is the problem with this ?

```
$('.post').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {  
         $(this).filter('anything here,a,div,.class,#id').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

where as this works fine.

```
$('.post').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {  
         $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
```

There is an anchor which I would like to show on mouse hover. Similar to Facebook

Comment: What is the context of $(this)?  Are you sure it has whatever you are filtering for?

Comment: Also, as a total aside, you may want to do this twice, once for on, one for off, and use show/hide explicitly.  There is a chance that if the cursor moves fast enough, it may not catch the off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` refers to your `.post` element.

`.filter()` removes anything that does not match the selector.

So in your given example if the `.post` element is not one of the following

```
'anything here,a,div,.class,#id'
```

it gets filtered out.

`.filter()` doesn't traverse. It takes a jQuery set and reduces it to the elements that match the selector given.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

---

**EDIT:**

There are lots of ways to traverse in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

To get all the `a` elements that are descendants of the `.post` element that received the event, you could do:

```
$(this).find('a');
```

Which traversal method to use will depend on your situation.

Comment: I got it, its using children(); Thanks for the knowledge

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the `.post` element that received the event. To access an descendant of `$(this)`, you could do `$(this).find('a')`. I'll update my answer.